# Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform. ZipException, message: invalid entry CRC gradle

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I used to work with Flutter v2.8 as much as I expected. because of the Firebase, I had to update flutter to v3 to get it to work.
After updating Flutter to v3, flutter said, "You have to get JDK version 11 or newer". I got confused why it was saying that because "flutter.dev" has mentioned the appropriate version of JDK for flutter is 8 so far!

I updated my JDK to 11 then, I got these weird errors that I've never had before! every time that I run or build an app it says something like the following pictures:
[image: failed to load image]

[image: failed to load image]

I created this project by using this command: `flutter create projectName`

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on Arch Linux 5.17.4-arch1-1, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.3.0 on channel stable at /home/john/Android/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ffccd96b62 (10 days ago), 2022-08-29 17:28:57 -0700
    • Engine revision 5e9e0e0aa8
    • Dart version 2.10
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/john/Android/Android/android-sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/john/Android/Android/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+10)
    • All Android licenses accepted

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 13.0.1
    • cmake version 3.23.1
    • ninja version 1.10.2
    • pkg-config version 1.8.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3)
    • IntelliJ at /usr/share/idea
    • Flutter plugin version 70.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 213.5744.122

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Arch Linux 5.17.4-arch1-1

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I've tried to delete ~/.gradle/cache all the time. but cannot produce an .apk app.
tried to downgrade flutter to version 2.8 but again still have the error.
for more information [see this GitHub link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111256)

(I created this project by using this command: `flutter create projectName`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new flutter project and copy the files from the current project.